# Получить значения всех input одинаковым class jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить значения всех input с одинаковым классом в переменную в формате `1, 2, 3, 4`

```js
function inp_val() {
  var values = $(".inp_val").val();
  alert(values);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="1">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="2">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="3">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="4">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="inp_val();">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте `map()`, `get()` и `join()`

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  const values = $(".inp_val").map( (i,el) => $(el).val() ).get().join(',');
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="1">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="2">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="3">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="4">
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин `$(".inp_val[data-select='1']")` или или отфильтровать, вроде `$(".inp_val").filter((i,el) => $(el).data('select') == 1)`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно "пройтись" по всем элементам с классом `.inp_val`

Используйте `.each()`, подробнее [здесь](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
function inp_val() {
  var str = '';
  var count = $(".inp_val").length;
  var i = 1;
  $(".inp_val").each(function(){
    str += parseInt($(this).val());
    if (i != count) {
        str += ", ";
    }
    i++;
  });
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="1">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="2">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="3">
<input type="number" class="inp_val" value="4">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="inp_val();">
```

Comment: Спасибо, но значения нужно занести в переменную в формате `1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: можно не в array а в string?

Comment: да, я уже потом понял, что нужен не массив, обновил

Comment: Спасибо большое